# After upgrading from Angular 5 to Angular 6: Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am getting following error like Unexpected value 'undefined' imported by the module 'AppModule', also the error in core.js file, this error come after angular upgrade from 5 to 6, This project made in Angular 5 but when i upgraded the version for node, cli, and ng then this kind of error happend, project compiled suceesfully but this error is showing in console, Please help me out to solve this.

Comment: It seems your question needs more information to be answered.

Comment: I have updated the info plz check

Comment: @TusharRmeshSaindane did you fixed your issue? I have the same problem.

Comment: Yes issue has been fixed .. What I did is removed the one unused plugin angular-storage .. You just check the each import in the import array and try to remove nd check if error disappears.

Comment: You can try using console.assert(Module, "Error message"). For example: import { MyModule } from './' console.assert(MyModule, "MyModule missing"); That way you can narrow down which module it is.

Comment: @MarkoŽivković Thank you for enlightening me.